# Why do we have the resources tag on the main site?

Tags: discussion, tags

[One of our more disgruntled users](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2025/i-need-a-good-resource-for-looking-up-particles) asks a very good question. Why do we have the [resources](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) tag on the main site when questions asking for learning resources are off topic?

Should we remove this tag to avoid misleading users? Is there some legitimate purpose to having it? If so I think the description would need changing to explain what an acceptable usage would be.

Comment: Reading most of the questions, they don't seem to look for Japanese language resources either... though the "**reference**" [tag synonym](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags/resources/synonyms) is also interesting... but, they both look like [meta tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/)?

Answer (score 1):

As this [resource page](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese) does exist, personally as a user I don't find much practicality for the tag itself on the types of questions I'm envisioning would be on-topic, per the Stack's [on-topic](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page. Most of what I can think of would fall under primarily opinion-based.

At the very least, I'd suggest adding that resource page, or some semblance of it, to the [Help Center](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help) itself to inform users about its existence. Especially for new users that cannot participate in Meta because of reputation and are more inclined to make questions that may be out of the scope of the site. Perhaps even clarify it under the site Tour's question recommendation guidelines.

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279847/how-can-we-add-a-useful-resources-to-the-help-center) could help in working out a way to incorporate this style into the Stack. The example given is the page for the [Buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) Stack.

If the tag will still be preserved in case of any question that does merit it (I'm having a hard time thinking of one personally, to be honest), I do agree that the description should be updated to reflect good use-cases.